# How can I get the observation number for each observation date for each id

Tags: sql, row-number

With the following query I can get the number of observations for each `ani_id` in a table:

```sql
select ani_id, obs_date, count(ani_id) OVER (PARTITION BY ani_id) as obs_nb 
from v_metadata_all group by ani_id, cap_date
```

| ani_id | obs_date | obs_nb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2855 | 2005-06-15 | 1 |
| 2856 | 2005-06-15 | 1 |
| 2857 | 2005-06-15 | 2 |
| 2857 | 2009-08-28 | 2 |
| 2858 | 2005-08-11 | 1 |

How can I get `obs_nb` as the sum of previous obs for each `ani_id` (`ani_id` could have between 1 and 5 observations in this table, not only 2)

| ani_id | obs_date | obs_nb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2855 | 2005-06-15 | 1 |
| 2856 | 2005-06-15 | 1 |
| 2857 | 2005-06-15 | 1 |
| 2857 | 2009-08-28 | 2 |
| 2858 | 2005-08-11 | 1 |

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `ROW_NUMBER` in this case, not `COUNT`:

```sql
SELECT ani_id, obs_date,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ani_id ORDER BY obs_date) AS obs_nb
FROM v_metadata_all;
```